# Take one array and combine it into another array

Tags: php, arrays

Hey Guys I have a quick question. I have an array that is as follows:

```
[0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "Prod ID"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
```

Now this array has all of the orders from a given group of people. This means that product ID will be listed more then once.

I am trying to combine them and increment the qty so that I can pull a report against the top 5 products sold. But I am not sure how to accomplish this as I am new to arrays.

I tried putting it into a loop and setting it to a second array, then if the product ID matched one in the existing array, it would add the qty values together.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Comment: I think I know what you want but if you provide an example of array a + b = c I can be sure.

Comment: Sorry I have been away from the computer for a few days. Actually all the data is in on array. I was just adding it to a second array so that I can manipulate it without messing with the original. So that I can use that data somewhere else in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, what you do here is that you group them to another array and loop them using the id, making it a key. When a key is assigned, it is pushed inside normally, if it already exists, just add the existing quantity to the one on the current loop. Example:

```
$new_data = array();
foreach($data as $value) {
    // simple initialization
    if(!isset($new_data[$value['id']])) {
        $new_data[$value['id']] = array('id' => $value['id'], 'qty' => 0);
    }
    // then sum up the quantity
    $new_data[$value['id']]['qty'] += $value['qty'];
}

$new_data = array_values($new_data); // simple reindex
```

Then to get the top 5, sort it to descending first, get slice the array to get the 5.

```
usort($new_data, function($a, $b){
    return $b['qty'] - $a['qty']; // sort descending
});
// get top 5
$top_5 = array_slice($new_data, 0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
foreach ($arr as $value)
    $newArr[$value['id']] = (isset($newArr[$value['id']])) ? $newArr[$value['id']] + $value['qty'] : $value['qty'] ;
```

Here an example how you should do it:

```
$test = [
  [
    "id" => "1",
    "qty" => "2"
  ],
  [
    "id" => "1",
    "qty" => "2"
  ],

  [
    "id" => "2",
    "qty" => "2"
  ],

  [
    "id" => "4",
    "qty" => "1"
  ],

  [
    "id" => "2",
    "qty" => "3"
  ],
  [
    "id" => "4",
    "qty" => "1"
  ]
];

foreach ($test as $value)
    $newArr[$value['id']] = (isset($newArr[$value['id']])) ? $newArr[$value['id']] + $value['qty'] : $value['qty'] ;

arsort($newArr);

print_r($newArr);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [2] => 5
    [1] => 4
    [4] => 2
)
```

Now you have an `id` as `key` and the sum of the `qty` related to this `id` as a `value`. It was sorted with **[arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)** so you can treat the informations easily.